# html document parsing issue

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have an issue with HtmlAgilityPack. I load the document from the stream and just save it without doing any kind of manipulation on the document. The document contains `header` , `body` , `footer`.The structure of header and footer is exactly same. And then return the `Filecontentresult` object. Code :

```
HtmlDocument ndoc = new HtmlDocument();
ndoc.Load(stream);                        //load from stream                          

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
   ndoc.Save(ms);                         //save back in stream
   ms.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
   fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
}

FileContentResult file = File(fileBytes, "text/html");
return file;
```

When i saw the document in the browser then everything was there but footer disappeared. Then i used `OptionOutputAsXml` by this footer comes but the contents of footer was still disappeared.

Now if i used the following code. Just removing the htmlagilitypack. Directly creating the FileContentResult from the stream. Then everything is perfect and on there own positions.Code:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
   stream.CopyTo(ms);            //copy stream contents in memorystream object
   fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
}

FileContentResult file = File(fileBytes, "text/html");
return file;
```

Can anybody please explain me whats the problem with HtmlAgilityPack ?

Comment: Have you tried to see if this is a problem with the encoding ? Try setting the Encoding property of the HtmlDocument object to the encoding used by your html page.

Comment: I would guess there is invalid markup. HtmlAgilityPack does not always do a great job with broken tags. Try validating the document online to be sure it's correct.

Comment: please provide your HTML example